# Tunnel Server Traffic through VPN but keep SSH Access

Tags: ssh, vpn

I would like to tunnel the traffic on my Server through a VPN.

The problem is that when I activate the VPN through openVpn I loose the connection to the server through SSH and have to restart the server through a hard reboot.

Is there a way of routing all traffic through the VPN except SSH?

Id also like this to only be temporary, meaning that I would like to be able to switch it off and just let the traffic go through normal channels.

I already tried the solution posted here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145635/debian-cli-torrent-program-through-vpn/145783#145783 but it did not work.

**Additional Info:**

```
route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I get locked out directly when starting OpenVPN. Also my server should run as a client, routing all its traffic through another server.

**EDIT:**

I followed the explanation from here [Anonymizing OpenVPN Allow SSH Access to Internal Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/425493/anonymizing-openvpn-allow-ssh-access-to-internal-server/444631#444631) .

Now I am running

**openvpn --config USVPN.ovpn --script-security 3 system --up /home/user/startVPNScript.sh**

with the startVPNScript.sh containing

```
ip rule add fwmark 65 table novpn
sudo ip route add default via XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX dev eth0 table novpn
ip route flush cache
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 65
```

I have also executed this:

```
echo "201 novpn" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

and it is permanent.

But after executing the openVPN command I still get locked out and have to do a Hard reboot through the ControlPanel of the ServerProvider.

**EDIT2**

Here are my Routing and firewall rules before starting the VPN ( Everything is empty to test it )

```
#novpn route table
default via DEFAULT.GATEWAY dev eth0

#normal route table

default DEFAULT.GATEWAY dev eth0  metric 100
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY

#iptable mangle

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        
MARK       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh MARK set 0x41

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination      


#iptable main

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Here are the rules after the OpenVPN connection has been established:

```
#novpn route table

default via DEFAULT.GATEWAY dev eth0

#normal route table

0.0.0.0/1 via 10.165.1.5 dev tun0
default via DEFAULT.GATEWAY dev eth0  metric 100
10.165.1.1 via 10.165.1.5 dev tun0
10.165.1.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.165.1.6
108.61.13.43 via DEFAULT.GATEWAY dev eth0
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.165.1.5 dev tun0
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY

#iptable mangle

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MARK       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh MARK set 0x41

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

#iptable main

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: usually ssh should continue to works since a route via default gateway is preserved to be able to reach the openvpn server. Can you provide additional information, like route -n before and after openvpn activation?

Comment: Ive addded information on how firewall and routes are before and after the vpn activation.